# To generate all the prime numbers using the isprime/1 build in function. Prolog

Tags: prolog, primes

Question ask:
?- prime(X).

The solution should look like:

```
X = 1;
X = 1;
X = 2;
X = 3;
X = 5;
X ....
```

So this is what i have until now:
prime(X) :- repeat, incr(X,X), isprime(X).

```
incr(X,X1) :- X1 is X+1.

isprime(X):-
    Y is 2, 
    X > 1, 
    \+div(X,Y).


div(X,Y):-
    N is Y*Y,
    N =< X,
    X mod Y =:= 0.

div(X,Y):-
    Y < X, 
    Y1 is Y+1, 
    div(X,Y1).
```

Comment: `incr(X, X)` can never be satisfied, since no number is equal to its successor.

Comment: yes, it's truth but then how could you initiate X to let's say 1 in order to start to the increment. So basically im trying to test every integer in isprime in order to determine all the prime number. Otherwise prolog tells me that they do not have suffiante data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following alternative for the `incr/2` predicate:

```
incr(I, I).
incr(I, K) :-
    J is I + 1,
    incr(J, K).
```

Call it using the goal:

```
| ?- incr(1,X), isprime(X).
?- incr(1,X), isprime(X).
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 5 ;
X = 7 ;
X = 11 ;
X = 13 ;
...
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much, I was starting to lose patience with that incr predicate.